# object has no attribute 'results' polygon.io API

Tags: python, stock, polygon.io

I'm pulling down a bunch of tickers from the polygon.io:

```
   from polygon import RESTClient
    key = 'KEY'
    all_tickers = []
    with RESTClient(key) as client:
        next_url = None
        while True:
            if next_url is None:
                tickers = client.reference_tickers_v3(type="CS")
            else:
                tickers = client._handle_response("ReferenceTickersV3ApiResponse", next_url, {})
            all_tickers.extend(tickers.results)
            if hasattr(tickers, 'next_url'):
                next_url = tickers.next_url
            else:
                break
                
    print(all_tickers)
```

I'm then trying to loop through the tickers and pull in the daily data for each one:

```
 with RESTClient(key) as client:
        from_ = "2022-01-01"
        to = "2022-02-01"
        
        for i in all_tickers:
            ticker =  i['ticker']
            resp = client.stocks_equities_aggregates(ticker, 1, "day", from_, to, unadjusted=False)

            print(f"Minute aggregates for {resp.ticker} between {from_} and {to}.")

            for result in resp.results:
                if result is None:
                    print('nothing')
                else:
                    print(result, 'result')
```

My problem is I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'StocksEquitiesAggregatesApiResponse' object has no attribute 'results'
```

Here's my output:

```
Minute aggregates for A between 2022-01-01 and 2022-02-01.
{'v': 1606323.0, 'vw': 155.8021, 'o': 159, 'c': 156.48, 'h': 159.44, 'l': 153.93, 't': 1641186000000, 'n': 24318} result
{'v': 2233958.0, 'vw': 151.518, 'o': 155.49, 'c': 151.19, 'h': 155.63, 'l': 149.7, 't': 1641272400000, 'n': 34707} result
{'v': 2370529.0, 'vw': 149.9716, 'o': 150.83, 'c': 148.6, 'h': 153.1, 'l': 148.53, 't': 1641358800000, 'n': 27421} result
{'v': 2298277.0, 'vw': 148.4397, 'o': 148.85, 'c': 149.12, 'h': 149.96, 'l': 145.58, 't': 1641445200000, 'n': 34441} result
{'v': 2058658.0, 'vw': 146.4352, 'o': 149.12, 'c': 145.15, 'h': 149.73, 'l': 145.09, 't': 1641531600000, 'n': 28611} result
{'v': 2548145.0, 'vw': 143.2162, 'o': 143.29, 'c': 145.16, 'h': 145.31, 'l': 140.86, 't': 1641790800000, 'n': 37241} result
{'v': 2194208.0, 'vw': 146.0091, 'o': 145, 'c': 146.64, 'h': 146.94, 'l': 143.81, 't': 1641877200000, 'n': 22781} result
{'v': 2250847.0, 'vw': 149.3025, 'o': 147.8, 'c': 149.51, 'h': 150.39, 'l': 147.55, 't': 1641963600000, 'n': 27392} result
{'v': 1741764.0, 'vw': 145.7333, 'o': 149.46, 'c': 145.17, 'h': 149.54, 'l': 144.85, 't': 1642050000000, 'n': 23437} result
{'v': 2225442.0, 'vw': 143.9446, 'o': 144.04, 'c': 144.68, 'h': 145.15, 'l': 142.36, 't': 1642136400000, 'n': 28295} result
{'v': 1907368.0, 'vw': 141.2762, 'o': 142.42, 'c': 140.47, 'h': 143.24, 'l': 140.34, 't': 1642482000000, 'n': 27031} result
{'v': 1472206.0, 'vw': 141.538, 'o': 140.67, 'c': 140.43, 'h': 143.6, 'l': 140.26, 't': 1642568400000, 'n': 23595} result
{'v': 1861384.0, 'vw': 140.9367, 'o': 141.38, 'c': 139.48, 'h': 143.14, 'l': 139.05, 't': 1642654800000, 'n': 26612} result
{'v': 1878663.0, 'vw': 138.4591, 'o': 139.54, 'c': 137.51, 'h': 140.49, 'l': 137.49, 't': 1642741200000, 'n': 27133} result
{'v': 2155299.0, 'vw': 135.3192, 'o': 136.38, 'c': 138.12, 'h': 138.49, 'l': 131.28, 't': 1643000400000, 'n': 32745} result
{'v': 1705313.0, 'vw': 134.473, 'o': 135.36, 'c': 134.57, 'h': 136.62, 'l': 132.65, 't': 1643086800000, 'n': 24457} result
{'v': 1999575.0, 'vw': 134.5836, 'o': 135.54, 'c': 133.51, 'h': 138.0454, 'l': 132.27, 't': 1643173200000, 'n': 28088} result
{'v': 1715819.0, 'vw': 133.1775, 'o': 135.28, 'c': 132.09, 'h': 136.36, 'l': 131.68, 't': 1643259600000, 'n': 25556} result
{'v': 2174805.0, 'vw': 135.3363, 'o': 133, 'c': 137.06, 'h': 137.4, 'l': 131.215, 't': 1643346000000, 'n': 21446} result
{'v': 1702950.0, 'vw': 138.8672, 'o': 137.32, 'c': 139.32, 'h': 139.47, 'l': 136.9729, 't': 1643605200000, 'n': 21984} result
{'v': 1655987.0, 'vw': 140.2601, 'o': 140.53, 'c': 141.03, 'h': 141.27, 'l': 138.45, 't': 1643691600000, 'n': 25755} result
Minute aggregates for AA between 2022-01-01 and 2022-02-01.
{'v': 6208442.0, 'vw': 60.9882, 'o': 60.24, 'c': 60.36, 'h': 62.61, 'l': 60.09, 't': 1641186000000, 'n': 49209} result
{'v': 7943653.0, 'vw': 58.135, 'o': 60.68, 'c': 57.53, 'h': 61.15, 'l': 57.21, 't': 1641272400000, 'n': 59085} result
{'v': 7599751.0, 'vw': 60.0291, 'o': 58.95, 'c': 58.55, 'h': 61.79, 'l': 58.445, 't': 1641358800000, 'n': 65793} result
{'v': 4363058.0, 'vw': 58.3964, 'o': 58.94, 'c': 58.45, 'h': 59.4911, 'l': 57.25, 't': 1641445200000, 'n': 39017} result
{'v': 8071270.0, 'vw': 61.7246, 'o': 60.14, 'c': 62.37, 'h': 62.89, 'l': 59.65, 't': 1641531600000, 'n': 62728} result
{'v': 5653472.0, 'vw': 61.268, 'o': 61.62, 'c': 61.54, 'h': 62.71, 'l': 60.441, 't': 1641790800000, 'n': 43504} result
{'v': 6003582.0, 'vw': 61.0876, 'o': 60.71, 'c': 62.2, 'h': 62.25, 'l': 59.12, 't': 1641877200000, 'n': 50028} result
{'v': 6434989.0, 'vw': 62.1745, 'o': 63.66, 'c': 61.88, 'h': 64.37, 'l': 60.86, 't': 1641963600000, 'n': 53063} result
{'v': 5769838.0, 'vw': 61.5961, 'o': 61.75, 'c': 60.51, 'h': 63.26, 'l': 60.37, 't': 1642050000000, 'n': 46975} result
{'v': 4397108.0, 'vw': 60.5607, 'o': 60.27, 'c': 61.39, 'h': 61.44, 'l': 59.34, 't': 1642136400000, 'n': 41558} result
{'v': 5994091.0, 'vw': 60.0163, 'o': 60.5, 'c': 60.05, 'h': 61.56, 'l': 58.8, 't': 1642482000000, 'n': 55228} result
{'v': 7851084.0, 'vw': 60.0468, 'o': 61.39, 'c': 59.63, 'h': 61.93, 'l': 58.885, 't': 1642568400000, 'n': 62775} result
{'v': 15925959.0, 'vw': 62.0662, 'o': 62.1, 'c': 61.25, 'h': 64.25, 'l': 59.97, 't': 1642654800000, 'n': 127187} result
{'v': 11024982.0, 'vw': 57.5373, 'o': 60.02, 'c': 56.21, 'h': 60.15, 'l': 56.04, 't': 1642741200000, 'n': 99811} result
{'v': 9209629.0, 'vw': 56.091, 'o': 53.81, 'c': 58.02, 'h': 58.2, 'l': 53.26, 't': 1643000400000, 'n': 83494} result
{'v': 7780587.0, 'vw': 59.9004, 'o': 57.51, 'c': 61.21, 'h': 61.6, 'l': 56.7608, 't': 1643086800000, 'n': 66222} result
{'v': 9267426.0, 'vw': 61.8703, 'o': 61.54, 'c': 60.75, 'h': 63.64, 'l': 59.88, 't': 1643173200000, 'n': 76224} result
{'v': 6445290.0, 'vw': 59.0007, 'o': 60.6, 'c': 58.03, 'h': 61.6599, 'l': 57.47, 't': 1643259600000, 'n': 55506} result
{'v': 6987869.0, 'vw': 56.9155, 'o': 58, 'c': 57.4, 'h': 58.39, 'l': 55.58, 't': 1643346000000, 'n': 62130} result
{'v': 7206053.0, 'vw': 56.1436, 'o': 56.94, 'c': 56.71, 'h': 57.02, 'l': 55.02, 't': 1643605200000, 'n': 59567} result
{'v': 5939348.0, 'vw': 57.6426, 'o': 57.99, 'c': 58.17, 'h': 58.44, 'l': 56.73, 't': 1643691600000, 'n': 55371} result
Minute aggregates for AAC between 2022-01-01 and 2022-02-01.
{'v': 205721, 'vw': 9.7563, 'o': 9.75, 'c': 9.76, 'h': 9.77, 'l': 9.75, 't': 1641186000000, 'n': 272} result
{'v': 1523384.0, 'vw': 9.751, 'o': 9.77, 'c': 9.78, 'h': 9.78, 'l': 9.745, 't': 1641272400000, 'n': 1431} result
{'v': 97970, 'vw': 9.7777, 'o': 9.75, 'c': 9.79, 'h': 9.79, 'l': 9.75, 't': 1641358800000, 'n': 413} result
{'v': 38331, 'vw': 9.7725, 'o': 9.79, 'c': 9.76, 'h': 9.79, 'l': 9.75, 't': 1641445200000, 'n': 499} result
{'v': 216378, 'vw': 9.7519, 'o': 9.75, 'c': 9.77, 'h': 9.78, 'l': 9.75, 't': 1641531600000, 'n': 138} result
{'v': 16220, 'vw': 9.7657, 'o': 9.79, 'c': 9.77, 'h': 9.79, 'l': 9.75, 't': 1641790800000, 'n': 211} result
{'v': 9403, 'vw': 9.7541, 'o': 9.76, 'c': 9.77, 'h': 9.77, 'l': 9.75, 't': 1641877200000, 'n': 179} result
{'v': 9311, 'vw': 9.7626, 'o': 9.76, 'c': 9.76, 'h': 9.77, 'l': 9.76, 't': 1641963600000, 'n': 103} result
{'v': 33525, 'vw': 9.7611, 'o': 9.78, 'c': 9.76, 'h': 9.78, 'l': 9.76, 't': 1642050000000, 'n': 642} result
{'v': 211170, 'vw': 9.7413, 'o': 9.76, 'c': 9.74, 'h': 9.76, 'l': 9.74, 't': 1642136400000, 'n': 359} result
{'v': 215143, 'vw': 9.7316, 'o': 9.73, 'c': 9.73, 'h': 9.75, 'l': 9.7, 't': 1642482000000, 'n': 546} result
{'v': 232058, 'vw': 9.7308, 'o': 9.73, 'c': 9.74, 'h': 9.74, 'l': 9.73, 't': 1642568400000, 'n': 773} result
{'v': 113445, 'vw': 9.7337, 'o': 9.73, 'c': 9.74, 'h': 9.75, 'l': 9.73, 't': 1642654800000, 'n': 408} result
{'v': 1164821.0, 'vw': 9.7302, 'o': 9.74, 'c': 9.74, 'h': 9.74, 'l': 9.72, 't': 1642741200000, 'n': 544} result
{'v': 143194, 'vw': 9.7235, 'o': 9.72, 'c': 9.7, 'h': 9.74, 'l': 9.7, 't': 1643000400000, 'n': 569} result
{'v': 771480, 'vw': 9.702, 'o': 9.7, 'c': 9.72, 'h': 9.73, 'l': 9.7, 't': 1643086800000, 'n': 481} result
{'v': 155088, 'vw': 9.7176, 'o': 9.7111, 'c': 9.71, 'h': 9.73, 'l': 9.71, 't': 1643173200000, 'n': 533} result
{'v': 2597988.0, 'vw': 9.7081, 'o': 9.72, 'c': 9.715, 'h': 9.72, 'l': 9.7, 't': 1643259600000, 'n': 459} result
{'v': 32932, 'vw': 9.7059, 'o': 9.7, 'c': 9.72, 'h': 9.72, 'l': 9.7, 't': 1643346000000, 'n': 157} result
{'v': 34893, 'vw': 9.7202, 'o': 9.71, 'c': 9.72, 'h': 9.73, 'l': 9.71, 't': 1643605200000, 'n': 129} result
{'v': 49625, 'vw': 9.7323, 'o': 9.71, 'c': 9.74, 'h': 9.75, 'l': 9.71, 't': 1643691600000, 'n': 269} result
Minute aggregates for AACI between 2022-01-01 and 2022-02-01.
{'v': 112300, 'vw': 9.8232, 'o': 9.81, 'c': 9.91, 'h': 9.91, 'l': 9.81, 't': 1641186000000, 'n': 66} result
{'v': 1799, 'vw': 9.8753, 'o': 9.87, 'c': 9.9, 'h': 9.9, 'l': 9.865, 't': 1641272400000, 'n': 12} result
{'v': 447937, 'vw': 9.8, 'o': 9.8, 'c': 9.8, 'h': 9.8, 'l': 9.8, 't': 1641445200000, 'n': 5} result
{'v': 970, 'vw': 9.8643, 'o': 9.89, 'c': 9.87, 'h': 9.89, 'l': 9.8108, 't': 1641531600000, 'n': 12} result
{'v': 8345, 'vw': 9.8711, 'o': 9.84, 'c': 9.88, 'h': 9.89, 'l': 9.84, 't': 1641790800000, 'n': 35} result
{'v': 768, 'vw': 9.8518, 'o': 9.85, 'c': 9.85, 'h': 9.85, 'l': 9.85, 't': 1641877200000, 'n': 12} result
{'v': 37576, 'vw': 9.8501, 'o': 9.85, 'c': 9.86, 'h': 9.86, 'l': 9.85, 't': 1642050000000, 'n': 16} result
{'v': 1510, 'vw': 9.853, 'o': 9.85, 'c': 9.85, 'h': 9.8545, 'l': 9.85, 't': 1642136400000, 'n': 10} result
{'v': 17996, 'vw': 9.8423, 'o': 9.864, 'c': 9.85, 'h': 9.864, 'l': 9.84, 't': 1642482000000, 'n': 69} result
{'v': 21766, 'vw': 9.85, 'o': 9.8564, 'c': 9.85, 'h': 9.8564, 'l': 9.84, 't': 1642568400000, 'n': 20} result
{'v': 103, 'vw': 9.8401, 'o': 9.84, 'c': 9.84, 'h': 9.84, 'l': 9.84, 't': 1642654800000, 'n': 3} result
{'v': 204116, 'vw': 9.8142, 'o': 9.84, 'c': 9.81, 'h': 9.8404, 'l': 9.8, 't': 1642741200000, 'n': 716} result
{'v': 2315, 'vw': 9.822, 'o': 9.85, 'c': 9.8167, 'h': 9.87, 'l': 9.8167, 't': 1643000400000, 'n': 9} result
{'v': 12334, 'vw': 9.802, 'o': 9.825, 'c': 9.8, 'h': 9.825, 'l': 9.8, 't': 1643086800000, 'n': 26} result
{'v': 445, 'vw': 9.8, 'o': 9.8, 'c': 9.8, 'h': 9.8, 'l': 9.8, 't': 1643259600000, 'n': 5} result
{'v': 34013, 'vw': 9.8559, 'o': 9.83, 'c': 9.91, 'h': 9.95, 'l': 9.83, 't': 1643691600000, 'n': 124} result
Minute aggregates for AADI between 2022-01-01 and 2022-02-01.
{'v': 62017, 'vw': 24.6177, 'o': 24.46, 'c': 24.97, 'h': 25, 'l': 23.67, 't': 1641186000000, 'n': 1515} result
{'v': 106127, 'vw': 24.5493, 'o': 24.97, 'c': 24.49, 'h': 25.13, 'l': 24.16, 't': 1641272400000, 'n': 1909} result
{'v': 71124, 'vw': 23.1894, 'o': 24.5, 'c': 22.69, 'h': 24.6, 'l': 22.67, 't': 1641358800000, 'n': 1383} result
{'v': 131714, 'vw': 22.5708, 'o': 22.69, 'c': 22.58, 'h': 23.29, 'l': 22.05, 't': 1641445200000, 'n': 2686} result
{'v': 55025, 'vw': 22.0268, 'o': 22.44, 'c': 21.75, 'h': 22.74, 'l': 21.6, 't': 1641531600000, 'n': 1488} result
{'v': 65801, 'vw': 21.4205, 'o': 21.28, 'c': 21.88, 'h': 22.08, 'l': 20.67, 't': 1641790800000, 'n': 1305} result
{'v': 144496, 'vw': 23.8096, 'o': 22.76, 'c': 24.03, 'h': 24.86, 'l': 22.36, 't': 1641877200000, 'n': 2219} result
{'v': 196387, 'vw': 24.6995, 'o': 24.05, 'c': 24, 'h': 25.355, 'l': 23.515, 't': 1641963600000, 'n': 3160} result
{'v': 121495, 'vw': 23.2696, 'o': 23.78, 'c': 23.26, 'h': 23.9, 'l': 22.68, 't': 1642050000000, 'n': 2284} result
{'v': 142106, 'vw': 24.0981, 'o': 23.2, 'c': 24.51, 'h': 24.8, 'l': 23, 't': 1642136400000, 'n': 2340} result
{'v': 274538, 'vw': 22.7217, 'o': 24, 'c': 21.92, 'h': 24, 'l': 21.91, 't': 1642482000000, 'n': 4084} result
{'v': 344249, 'vw': 20.8055, 'o': 21.9, 'c': 19.94, 'h': 21.9, 'l': 19.925, 't': 1642568400000, 'n': 4688} result
{'v': 181528, 'vw': 20.4276, 'o': 19.94, 'c': 19.7, 'h': 21.42, 'l': 19.7, 't': 1642654800000, 'n': 2668} result
{'v': 170526, 'vw': 19.1647, 'o': 19.65, 'c': 19, 'h': 19.65, 'l': 18.56, 't': 1642741200000, 'n': 3127} result
{'v': 341151, 'vw': 17.9706, 'o': 18.7, 'c': 18.47, 'h': 19.51, 'l': 17.15, 't': 1643000400000, 'n': 3135} result
{'v': 125024, 'vw': 19.0888, 'o': 18.16, 'c': 19.39, 'h': 19.73, 'l': 18.1, 't': 1643086800000, 'n': 2297} result
{'v': 173235, 'vw': 19.5451, 'o': 19.59, 'c': 18.86, 'h': 20.92, 'l': 18.7, 't': 1643173200000, 'n': 2778} result
{'v': 168137, 'vw': 18.6189, 'o': 19.25, 'c': 18.56, 'h': 19.49, 'l': 18.38, 't': 1643259600000, 'n': 2485} result
{'v': 193384, 'vw': 17.9062, 'o': 18.24, 'c': 17.79, 'h': 18.83, 'l': 17.511, 't': 1643346000000, 'n': 3317} result
{'v': 137629, 'vw': 18.8928, 'o': 17.73, 'c': 19, 'h': 19.32, 'l': 17.73, 't': 1643605200000, 'n': 2734} result
{'v': 96935, 'vw': 19.0682, 'o': 19.16, 'c': 19.07, 'h': 19.5323, 'l': 18.72, 't': 1643691600000, 'n': 2146} result
Minute aggregates for AAIC between 2022-01-01 and 2022-02-01.
{'v': 60702, 'vw': 3.5587, 'o': 3.5, 'c': 3.56, 'h': 3.59, 'l': 3.5, 't': 1641186000000, 'n': 385} result
{'v': 68084, 'vw': 3.5922, 'o': 3.55, 'c': 3.58, 'h': 3.61, 'l': 3.55, 't': 1641272400000, 'n': 515} result
{'v': 83051, 'vw': 3.5949, 'o': 3.58, 'c': 3.53, 'h': 3.635, 'l': 3.53, 't': 1641358800000, 'n': 577} result
{'v': 68775, 'vw': 3.588, 'o': 3.55, 'c': 3.58, 'h': 3.61, 'l': 3.55, 't': 1641445200000, 'n': 434} result
{'v': 101412, 'vw': 3.614, 'o': 3.61, 'c': 3.59, 'h': 3.64, 'l': 3.59, 't': 1641531600000, 'n': 574} result
{'v': 92862, 'vw': 3.5719, 'o': 3.55, 'c': 3.57, 'h': 3.596, 'l': 3.55, 't': 1641790800000, 'n': 693} result
{'v': 61334, 'vw': 3.5934, 'o': 3.55, 'c': 3.61, 'h': 3.62, 'l': 3.55, 't': 1641877200000, 'n': 516} result
{'v': 69223, 'vw': 3.6051, 'o': 3.62, 'c': 3.59, 'h': 3.62, 'l': 3.59, 't': 1641963600000, 'n': 472} result
{'v': 59478, 'vw': 3.6034, 'o': 3.6, 'c': 3.58, 'h': 3.63, 'l': 3.58, 't': 1642050000000, 'n': 435} result
{'v': 55555, 'vw': 3.546, 'o': 3.51, 'c': 3.58, 'h': 3.59, 'l': 3.51, 't': 1642136400000, 'n': 362} result
{'v': 40123, 'vw': 3.5546, 'o': 3.53, 'c': 3.52, 'h': 3.586, 'l': 3.52, 't': 1642482000000, 'n': 498} result
{'v': 99546, 'vw': 3.4961, 'o': 3.46, 'c': 3.47, 'h': 3.52, 'l': 3.46, 't': 1642568400000, 'n': 464} result
{'v': 112002, 'vw': 3.4914, 'o': 3.48, 'c': 3.48, 'h': 3.54, 'l': 3.47, 't': 1642654800000, 'n': 681} result
{'v': 142444, 'vw': 3.4243, 'o': 3.49, 'c': 3.41, 'h': 3.49, 'l': 3.4, 't': 1642741200000, 'n': 613} result
{'v': 185877, 'vw': 3.3053, 'o': 3.42, 'c': 3.36, 'h': 3.42, 'l': 3.25, 't': 1643000400000, 'n': 1020} result
{'v': 94305, 'vw': 3.39, 'o': 3.34, 'c': 3.44, 'h': 3.46, 'l': 3.32, 't': 1643086800000, 'n': 840} result
{'v': 73169, 'vw': 3.4575, 'o': 3.48, 'c': 3.39, 'h': 3.4901, 'l': 3.3832, 't': 1643173200000, 'n': 932} result
{'v': 112655, 'vw': 3.375, 'o': 3.4, 'c': 3.31, 'h': 3.43, 'l': 3.31, 't': 1643259600000, 'n': 702} result
{'v': 67119, 'vw': 3.2877, 'o': 3.34, 'c': 3.31, 'h': 3.34, 'l': 3.25, 't': 1643346000000, 'n': 795} result
{'v': 110155, 'vw': 3.4097, 'o': 3.3, 'c': 3.43, 'h': 3.43, 'l': 3.3, 't': 1643605200000, 'n': 867} result
{'v': 84388, 'vw': 3.4423, 'o': 3.4, 'c': 3.44, 'h': 3.48, 'l': 3.39, 't': 1643691600000, 'n': 1000} result
Minute aggregates for AAL between 2022-01-01 and 2022-02-01.
{'v': 42891313.0, 'vw': 18.7823, 'o': 18.23, 'c': 18.75, 'h': 19.18, 'l': 18.2, 't': 1641186000000, 'n': 162180} result
{'v': 29266598.0, 'vw': 19.09, 'o': 19.215, 'c': 19.02, 'h': 19.46, 'l': 18.8504, 't': 1641272400000, 'n': 119439} result
{'v': 34447891.0, 'vw': 18.9205, 'o': 19.13, 'c': 18.68, 'h': 19.385, 'l': 18.51, 't': 1641358800000, 'n': 133198} result
{'v': 19097700.0, 'vw': 18.6698, 'o': 18.89, 'c': 18.57, 'h': 19.0599, 'l': 18.35, 't': 1641445200000, 'n': 91482} result
{'v': 42399468.0, 'vw': 19.211, 'o': 18.75, 'c': 19.28, 'h': 19.59, 'l': 18.58, 't': 1641531600000, 'n': 158244} result
{'v': 25707705.0, 'vw': 18.8635, 'o': 19.24, 'c': 18.79, 'h': 19.39, 'l': 18.68, 't': 1641790800000, 'n': 117681} result
{'v': 22531542.0, 'vw': 19.001, 'o': 18.88, 'c': 19.02, 'h': 19.205, 'l': 18.71, 't': 1641877200000, 'n': 97960} result
{'v': 41140852.0, 'vw': 18.6807, 'o': 19.16, 'c': 18.5, 'h': 19.255, 'l': 18.35, 't': 1641963600000, 'n': 151521} result
{'v': 55911766.0, 'vw': 19.3729, 'o': 18.73, 'c': 19.34, 'h': 19.7597, 'l': 18.63, 't': 1642050000000, 'n': 197015} result
{'v': 44983137.0, 'vw': 18.6557, 'o': 19.11, 'c': 18.49, 'h': 19.16, 'l': 18.4, 't': 1642136400000, 'n': 166866} result
{'v': 39855909.0, 'vw': 18.0989, 'o': 18.23, 'c': 17.9, 'h': 18.61, 'l': 17.77, 't': 1642482000000, 'n': 153703} result
{'v': 36133149.0, 'vw': 17.5146, 'o': 17.9, 'c': 17.31, 'h': 17.91, 'l': 17.29, 't': 1642568400000, 'n': 165519} result
{'v': 54892831.0, 'vw': 17.102, 'o': 17.63, 'c': 16.76, 'h': 17.7326, 'l': 16.6829, 't': 1642654800000, 'n': 221617} result
{'v': 52547514.0, 'vw': 16.3931, 'o': 16.77, 'c': 16.3, 'h': 16.78, 'l': 16.09, 't': 1642741200000, 'n': 217949} result
{'v': 60008675.0, 'vw': 15.8661, 'o': 15.85, 'c': 16.41, 'h': 16.44, 'l': 15.38, 't': 1643000400000, 'n': 229504} result
{'v': 42471591.0, 'vw': 16.2901, 'o': 16.05, 'c': 16.46, 'h': 16.54, 'l': 15.89, 't': 1643086800000, 'n': 169713} result
{'v': 39331762.0, 'vw': 16.6158, 'o': 16.7, 'c': 16.24, 'h': 16.97, 'l': 16.135, 't': 1643173200000, 'n': 146204} result
{'v': 43507377.0, 'vw': 16.0433, 'o': 16.425, 'c': 15.78, 'h': 16.84, 'l': 15.6226, 't': 1643259600000, 'n': 172213} result
{'v': 51662636.0, 'vw': 15.3385, 'o': 15.67, 'c': 15.64, 'h': 15.78, 'l': 14.905, 't': 1643346000000, 'n': 203975} result
{'v': 35533507.0, 'vw': 16.1221, 'o': 15.55, 'c': 16.47, 'h': 16.47, 'l': 15.4, 't': 1643605200000, 'n': 136379} result
{'v': 30688782.0, 'vw': 16.7612, 'o': 16.56, 'c': 16.83, 'h': 16.965, 'l': 16.4114, 't': 1643691600000, 'n': 125323} result
Minute aggregates for AAMC between 2022-01-01 and 2022-02-01.
```

I figure this is because it gets to a ticker and then doesn't have the results property. What's the correct way to handle this exception?

API documentation: https://polygon.io/docs/stocks/get_v2_aggs_ticker__stocksticker__range__multiplier___timespan___from___to

Answer (score 0):

I was using if statements (coming from a JS background), but had to use try-except instead:

```
  with RESTClient(key) as client:
        from_ = "2022-01-01"
        to = "2022-02-01"
        
        for i in all_tickers:
            ticker =  i['ticker']
            resp = client.stocks_equities_aggregates(ticker, 1, "day", from_, to, unadjusted=False)

            print(f"Minute aggregates for {resp.ticker} between {from_} and {to}.")

                    
            try:
                for result in resp.results:
                    print(result, 'result')
            except:
                print('nothing')
```

Further reading: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-attributeerror/